# Migration of Sendmail from RHEL 3 to RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, email, sendmail

We have a upcoming task of Migrating our Production mail server to a new environment. Mail Server is sendmail and OS is `RHEL 3`.

```
       sendmail-cf-8.12.11-4.RHEL3.4
```

We are planning to migrate on `RHEL 6` with the latest version of Sendmail

Few issues I am seeing is `sendmail.mc` does not exist on current mail server, only `sendmail.cf` exist.

I need clarifications on the following below points...

1.Not sure whether it is possible to generate `sendmail.mc` from `sendmail.cf`. In that case I could have tried to enable existing `sendmail.mc` settings in new mail server thus migrating to `RHEL 6` .

2. Can copy existing `sendmail.cf` to new mail server and restart sendmail . But this may lead to issues like deprecated configuration items and version mismatch.
3. Generating `sendmail.cf` in new mail server from existing `sendmail.cf` will be tough as this file is difficult to understand and not recommended.

Also any other suggestions to migrate to latest mailserver based on `sendmail.mc` missing on current scenario.

2. Now since we are planning to migrate to `RHEL 6`, we are not sure how to generate `sendmail.cf` file as `sendmail.mc` does not exist on current mail server. We can copy `sendmail.cf` from existing mail server but there will be version mismatch issue or may be some configuration items has been deprecated.

Comment: Please add the sendmail.mc to this question.

Comment: That is the whole issue. Sendmail.mc is missing

Comment: My fault then, I understood sendmail.mc was present in the legacy server. In the old days of yore, many sysadmins edited direct sendmail.cf...I do not recommend it. I have not used RH for quite a while, would you verify if the source package brings the default mc?

Answer (score 1):

The `sendmail.mc` is an m4 macro source file that when processed generates your `sendmail.cf`. It is normally not possible to generate in an automatic way a `sendmail.mc` from a `sendmail.mc`.

Whilst the `sendmail.mc` file in the legacy system was the source of the `sendmail.cf`that is present there, you have to double check whether there were posterior editions to `sendmail.cf` directly, as some less experienced system admins frequently did. If that is not the case, read on.

If `sendmail.mc`or `sendmail.cf` were never customized, and are the default from the distro, it could also be a safe be to use the new one as it is (highly doubtful, but must be said).

Otherwise, if `sendmail.cf` was never touched directly, and all work was done in top of the `sendmail.mc`, the original `sendmail.mc` can be used to generate a `sendmail.cf` in the destination system with minimal, or none changes with the command:

```
m4 /etc/sendmail.mc > /etc/sendmail.cf
```

To get to the point, it is highly doubtful the old `sendmail.cf` will work, as it will be obsolete; however `sendmail.mc` is a macro file, are there is a fairly chance it will compile cleanly; even if not, it can surely be used as the basis for the new config *if* it was used in the first place for producing the whole configuring.